# How to post list of users in Spring

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot, model

I have this domain class in Spring:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Like")
public class Like {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = User.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
@OnDelete(action= OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
Set<User> user;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "like", orphanRemoval = true ,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Picture.class)
@OnDelete(action= OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
Set<Picture> pictures;

public Like() {
}

public Like(Set<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
@JsonIgnore
public Set<User> getUser() {
    return user;
}
@JsonIgnore
public void setUser(Set<User> user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@JsonIgnore
public Set<Picture> getPictures() {
    return pictures;
}
@JsonIgnore
public void setPictures(Set<Picture> pictures) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
}
}
}
```

and I have this table in my sql script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `like` (
`id` INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` BIGINT,
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `user`(id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And this is a problem when I send post request in postman:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field 
 com.nyters.webapp.domain.User.id to java.util.HashSet

**ControllerLike.java**

```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("api/like")
  public class LikeController {

  private LikeService likeService;

  @Autowired
  public LikeController(LikeService likeService){
  this.likeService = likeService;
 }

   @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<LikeDTO> findOne(@PathVariable Long id) {
   LikeDTO pictureDTO = likeService.findOne(id);

   if (pictureDTO != null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(pictureDTO, HttpStatus.OK);
  } else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
  }

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<LikeDTO>> findAll() {
List<LikeDTO> likeDTOs = likeService.findAll();

if (likeDTOs != null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(likeDTOs, HttpStatus.OK);
} else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
}

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<LikeDTO> save(@RequestBody String likeDtoString) 
 throws 
 IOException {
  LikeDTO likeDTO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(likeDtoString, 
  LikeDTO.class);
  LikeDTO saved = likeService.save(likeDTO);

if (saved != null) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(saved, HttpStatus.OK);
} else {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
}
```

Comment: I try to send in postman this 
{

"user": [
 {
   "id": "1",
 "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
 "name": "John",
 "img": "fafaf43affaaf"
 },{
   "id": "2",
 "email": "john1.doe@gmail.com",
 "name": "John1",
 "img": "fafaf43afdsfffaaf"
 }
]
  
}

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments edit your question instead.

Comment: How does your controller look like or are you using Spring Data Rest?

Answer (score 0):

At first `@JsonIgnore` make your users not accessiable for entity from json.
At second you need to change `@ManyToOne` to `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany` for filed `Set<User> user` or change type to `User user`

**UPDATE**

Well, `ManyToOne` means that in current class you have just one element (in our case `User`. it`s looks as following:

```
class Like {
// init, class and bla-bla-bla

@ManyToOne(/*properties*/)
User user; // important - not Collection, Set or something else
```

and in this case your user class looks as follows:

```
class User {
// blablabla
@OneToMany(/*properties*/
Set<Like> likes;
```

So, you can imagine (?) it as follows: @external_filed To current_field. I hope you understand

Comment: Yes, but i want relationship @ManyToOne for filed Set<User> user, and I want to insert in table Like list of users who likes something

Comment: @ManyToOne means that you have in Like class one user and in User class many Like's

Comment: Can you show me how to set that relationship? In domain class user i have this 
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true ,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Like.class)
    @OnDelete(action= OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    Set<Like> likes;
And I want to have this in database, table like where i can store list of users

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper, I  have added ans with mapping,jus check it once

Comment: But I don't want one User i want list of them

Comment: Ok, better use `@OneToMany` in `Like` class and you got `Set<Users>` and `@ManyToOne` in `User` class and got `Like like`

Answer (score 0):

I guess prob is with your mapping

**Like.java**

```
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_Id")
@JsonIgnore
private List<User> userList;
//based on user_Id u can fetch userList from DB
```

**User.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_Id")
private Long user_Id;
```

Comment: Can you show me how to set that relationship? In domain class user i have this @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", orphanRemoval = true ,cascade= CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Like.class) @OnDelete(action= OnDeleteAction.CASCADE) Set<Like> likes; And I want to have this in database, table like where i can store list of users

Comment: @CrazyDeveloper, This will fetch u userList only,not one user